# Does ruby cron under Windows exist?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

My ruby application will be running on Windows XP. I need some kind of cron that will run tasks on regular basis. I want all this to be done in ruby.

Is there any **cron like ruby gem for Windows**?

I would like to have pure ruby solution. I know that Windows Scheduled Task thing exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gem [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) is the answer. Don't forget to use `scheduler.join`

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new

scheduler.every '1m' do
  puts "1 -  #{Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}"

end


scheduler.join
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Scheduled Task from the Task Scheduler* to call the ruby interpreter with the cron filename as a parameter. There is a plethora of options to control the execution of a task.

The following is an screenshot of the Scheduler of Windows 7 and with PHP but you get the idea.

[image: Screen Shot]

*Press Windows Key + R and type: %windir%\system32\taskschd.msc /s

*Start Menu\Accessories\System Tools\Task Scheduler

Comment: I was hoping for pure ruby option. If there is nothing like that I will have to use Windows Task Scheduler. Thank you.